# Unable to read NetCDF structure variable array subrange

Tags: java, hdf5, netcdf

I have an NCDF structure being retrieved from an HDF5 file, and I'm trying to read a subrange of an array variable using the Java NetCDF 4.3.16 library. I find the variable like this:

```
Variable netCDFVariable = netCDFFile.findVariable("/group/struct.var");
```

At this point I can read the entire variable if I want:

```
netCDFArray = netCDFVariable.read();
```

But let's say that the variable is an integer array of length 10, and I want to read just the subrange of indexes 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7:

```
Section section=new Section(new int[]{3}, new int[]{5});
netCDFArray = netCDFVariable.read(section);
```

But here `Variable.read(Section)` throws an `InvalidRangeException`. Tracing through the code, the variable checks its own internal `shape` variable, which happens to be `[]` and finds that to be invalid.

So why doesn't the variable have an appropriate `shape`? Do I have to read the variable first to get its correct shape? (That would of course defeat the purpose of trying to read a subrange in the first place.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of NetCDF 4.3.17 the implementations of `Variable.read()` and `Variable.read(Section)` differ considerably when reading a member of an array of structures, neither adhering to the API documentation. Below I present a workaround.

For illustration, let's say I have the following:

```
Structure {
  int foo;
    :_Unsigned = "true";
  int bar;
    :_Unsigned = "true";
} example(24);
```

This is a 24-element array named `example` of structures, each structure containing two members, `foo` and `bar`. Let us assume I get a reference to the `foo` member like so:

```
final Variable fooVariable = netcdfFile.findVariable("/blah/example.foo");
```

If I call `fooVariable.read()`, the API documentation says that I will get back the first value, because `foo` is part of a structure that is an element in an array. This is not what happens; instead, the library actually does some clever reading and returns the `foo` member from all the structures as a single array of `foo` values. This is the behavior I desire.

Unfortunately the `fooVariable.read(Section)` implementation does not have the same bit of clever code as does `fooVariable.read()`, and instead is written to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. (Through the lack of an added check the code doesn't even get that far, throwing an `InvalidRangeException` because it thinks the given `Section` is invalid. This is a pity, because (once a check is added to avoid an `InvalidRangeException`) the clever code from the `Variable.read()` implementation would work equally well for `Variable.read(Section)` with the insertion of only a single method argument on a single line!

Using the clever code from `Variable.read()` I have created a method that works around this problem, allowing a caller to ask for a section of an array with any variable. If the variable is a member of a structure in an array, the subrange of just that member will be read, effectively creating another version of the `fooVariable.read(Section)` method that has the same behavior as `fooVariable.read()` for structure members:

```
  /**
   * Reads an array of data from the provided NetCDF variable. If the variable is a member of a structure, that member is read
   * from all the structures in the array and returned as a single array containing that member from each structure.
   * @param variable The NetCDF variable to read.
   * @param section The section indicating the element of the array to read
   * @param indexEnd The ending source index, exclusive, or -1 if all available values should be read.
   * @return An array representing the requested range of values read for the given variable.
   * @throws IOException if there is an error reading the data.
   */
  public static Array readArray(final Variable variable, final Section section) throws IOException, InvalidRangeException {
    if (variable.isMemberOfStructure()) { //if the variable is member of a structure
      final Structure parentStructure = variable.getParentStructure().select(variable.getShortName()); //select just the member variable
      final ArrayStructure arrayStructure = (ArrayStructure) parentStructure.read(section); //read the array of structures
      return arrayStructure.extractMemberArray(arrayStructure.findMember(variable.getShortName())); //extract just the member into an array
    } else { //if the variable is not a member of a structure
      return variable.read(section); //just read the section directly from the variable
    }
  }
```

I reported this problem (now identified as NRW-974703) with [Unidata NetCDF Support](http://mailto%3asupport-netcdf-java@unidata.ucar.edu). At first I was told that these methods didn't apply to HDF5 and only apply to Unidata's own NetCDF file format. (This is completely incorrect.) Then I was told that I didn't understand the Java NetCDF API (although from the previous answer I question who exactly lacks understanding of the Unidata library). I have not yet received a response from Unidata after tracing down the specific problem code and providing the above workaround.